# Is it possible to use a Dell HBA330 in an HP Z2 G4 Workstation?

Tags: storage, pci-express, adapter

Trying to install a [Dell HBA330 SAS controller](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/hba330-12gbps-sas-hba-controller-non-raid-minicard/apd/405-aajw#polaris-pd) in an HP Z2 workstation.

Getting BIOS error. 3 Major/2 Minor beeps on start-up and nothing. Tried the card in another computer and it works without issue. Anyone know how to get this working with this computer?

Thank you!

Edit:

- This is a a DELL HBA330 J7TNV 12Gb/s 3rd Gen, it is also flashed in
  IT Mode.
- The HP workstation product number is [2YW27AV](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-z2-tower-g4-workstation/20063240/model/20063443?sku=2YW27AV)

Comment: 1) There are many HP Z2 workstations; what is the model part number of yours? Check the serial number sticker, it's normally on there. 2) Is the Dell controller you are adding the PCIe 3.0 Mini Card version? To answer both, please click [edit] and add that information to the Question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting some more, I figured out that if i remove some memory, it then works. I have 128GB of memory on this machine, which is the maximum. If I add all the memory + the card, it gives the error mention.

For now, I will mark this as resolved unless someone knows how to get the 128GB of memory + the card to work.